# Need to restart server again and again to make mui styles to work with nextjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I have followed the examples of Nextjs setup with MUI. And the styles are working for me but when I use makeStyles to override MUI CSS I need to restart the server again and again to see changes with the CSS iam overriding. How do I solve it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

thats because you are using material-ui v5 and using makeStyle
makeStyle is more compatible with v4
for nextjs you can use v4 or their boiler plate on v5 here :
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs
and for styling use sx props instead of makeStyle (check docs in mui.com)